# Forward Gmail via Filter to 3rd Party Email Address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'd like to be able to forward specific emails (identified via a Filter) to my TripIt account for points tracking. It seems as if the only way to auto-forward in Gmail is if you own the email address you want to forward to, and can provide verification.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

IFTTT.com might serve as a useful proxy. If you allow the service to access your gmail, it will effectively create a new email for you and send it to points@tripit.com when it receives an incoming email from a specified server.

Luckily, it seems AA, United, Southwest and others have fairly non-generic emails for their monthly statements which should help (and separate spam emails with point bonuses which can confuse the point tracker).

https://ifttt.com/recipes/196688-send-tripit-your-monthly-united-mileage-plus-statement-for-point-tracking

Answer (score 1):

Set up a secondary gmail address.

Add that address to Tripit's scan feature.

Make a filter in your primary email to forward travel-related emails to the secondary account that is scanned by Tripit.

Comment: Users may not be familiar with Tripit's scan feature.  Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).